# Change the visibility of label within a datalist

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How can I change the visibility of a label with a datalist using asp.net and C#-4.0 ? I tried the following code but unfortunately it is not working:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            viewall();

        }

    protected void viewall()

    {
        MySqlCommand objacess = new MySqlCommand();

        objacess.CommandText = "select * from product_tbl ";

        DataTable dobj = new DataTable();
        dobj = objDataAccess.GetRecords(objacess);
        for (int i = 0; i < dobj.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string d = dobj.Rows[i]["pdiscount"].ToString();
            int di = Convert.ToInt32(d);
            if (di > 0)
            {
                Label lbldisc = (Label)DataList1.FindControl("lbl_discount");

               lbldisc.Visible=true; 
            }
        }

    DataList1.DataSource = dobj;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
```

When I try this I receive the following **Error**:

> Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: you don't say WHERE the error happens. are you sure your variable dobj is NOT null? what about the variable "d"? is it null when you read the column of data?

Comment: Error at lbldisc.Visible=true;

Comment: in which case lbldisc is not found....

Answer (score 0):

dear friend your code is not finding the lable control thats why its giving you this error and all our databound countrol are working on then indexes so change you this line

```
Label lbldisc = (Label)DataList1.FindControl("lbl_discount");
```

to the following

```
Label lbldisc = (Label)DataList1.item[i].FindControl("lbl_discount");
```

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: do one thing for your solution use itemdatabound event of datalist let me send you example

Comment: ok 1st try onething put this 2 line of code before for loop DataList1.DataSource = dobj;
    DataList1.DataBind();

Comment: Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an objec

Answer (score 0):

you need to write hide code after binding the values.

```
//bind value to datalist
DataList1.DataSource = dobj;
DataList1.DataBind();
//after binding hide the label
for (int i = 0; i < dobj.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string d = dobj.Rows[i]["pdiscount"].ToString();
    int di = Convert.ToInt32(d);
    if (di > 0)
    {
        Label lbldisc = (Label)DataList1.FindControl("lbl_discount");
        lbldisc.Visible=true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: How to hide the label after binding ?

Comment: you need to loop through number of records and find for each row and then hide it.

Comment: @user3700005 why you want to hide If for getting values form it then use `hidden field` rather than `label`.